# Remove last slash in URL, only if no directory is present

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove the last `/` from a URL, but only if there is no directory present. Is there a way to check `if(3 slashes only && not https) remove slash`? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

#### What I have so far

```php
$url = preg_replace(array('{http://}', '{/$}'), '', $project->url);
```

Current outputs:

```
http://www.example.org/          => www.example.org
https://www.example.org/         => https://www.example.org
http://www.example.org/dir/      => www.example.org/dir
https://www.example.org/dir/     => https://www.example.org/dir
http://www.example.org/dir/dir/  => www.example.org/dir/dir
https://www.example.org/dir/dir/ => https://www.example.org/dir/dir
```

#### What I want to get

```
http://www.example.org/          => www.example.org
https://www.example.org/         => https://www.example.org
http://www.example.org/dir/      => www.example.org/dir/
https://www.example.org/dir/     => https://www.example.org/dir/
http://www.example.org/dir/dir/  => www.example.org/dir/dir/
https://www.example.org/dir/dir/ => https://www.example.org/dir/dir/
```

Comment: You are going to have to actually check if there is a directory first before leaving or deleting the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$url = preg_replace('~^(?:(https://)|http://)?+([^/]++)(?:(/[^\s"']++)|/)?+~', '$1$2$3', $url);
```

or more simple (if `$url` contains only an url)

```
$url = preg_replace('~^(?:(https://)|http://)?+([^/]++)(?:(/.++)|/)?+~', '$1$2$3', $url);
```

Note that with these patterns:

`www.example.org/` give `www.example.org`

and

`http://www.example.org` give `www.example.org`

**second pattern details**

```
~                         # pattern delimiter
^                         # anchor for the begining of the string
(?:(https://)|http://)?+  # optional "http(s)://" , but only "https://" 
                          # is captured in group $1 (not "http://") 
([^/]++)                  # capturing group $2: all characters except "/"
(?:(/.++)|/)?+            # a slash followed by characters (capturing group $3)
                          # or only a slash (not captured),
                          # all this part is optional "?+"
~                         # pattern delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the second one. Any chance you can explain it a little bit more so I understand what it's doing and see the order of operations there? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but will do the job:

```
$num_slash = substr_count($url, '/');
if ($num_slash > 3)
{
    // i have directory
    if (strpos($url, ':') == 4)
        $url = substr($url, 7);
    // this will take care of 
    // http://www.example.org/dir/dir/ => www.example.org/dir/dir/
}
else
{
    $url = preg_replace(array('{http://}', '{/$}'), '', $project->url);
    // this will take care of as you already mentioned
    // http://www.example.org/  => www.example.org
    // https://www.example.org/ => https://www.example.org
}
// so whenever you have https, nothing will happen to your url
```